# Iterating through dict of dicts

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, in this fashion:

```py
scores = {'default': {'MSE': [[1.0,2.0], [3.0,4.0]], 'R2': [[2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0]]},
        'RBF': {'MSE': [[3.0,4.0],[5.0,6.0]], 'R2': [[4.0,5.0],[6.0,7.0]]}
        }
```

And I need the list of numbers inside the second dictionary to be a `np.array`, because I want to plot them in a graph and each column goes in a different graph, and list indexing is not able to separate the columns correctly.

To access each list, I'd do `scores['default']['MSE']` and that returns `[[1.0, 2.0],[3.0,4.0]` I need the values by column (so for the first graph I'd need the values `[2.0, 4.0]`) and list indexing is not versatile enough.

I want to apply the `np.array` to those lists so I can index them easier, and I've tried two methods:

**Method 1**: Using `map()`

```py
import numpy as np

scores = {'default': {'MSE': [[1.0,2.0], [2.0,3.0]], 'R2': [[2.0,3.0],[3.0,4.0]]},
        'RBF': {'MSE': [[3.0,4.0],[4.0,5.0]], 'R2': [[4.0,5.0],[5.0,6.0]]}
        }

scores = map(np.array, scores)
```

This method does not work, because I need to apply the function to the internal list, not the dictionaries.

There's also a variation of this method that gets me closer but does not work, because it destroys the dictionary keys in the process (just change the map line  to this):

```py
scores = [list(map(np.array, scores[k][k2])) for k in scores.keys() for k2 in scores[k].keys()]
```

**Method 2**: Using for loops

```py
import numpy as np

scores = {'default': {'MSE': [[1.0,2.0], [2.0,3.0]], 'R2': [[2.0,3.0],[3.0,4.0]]},
        'RBF': {'MSE': [[3.0,4.0],[4.0,5.0]], 'R2': [[4.0,5.0],[5.0,6.0]]}
        }

for k in scores.keys():
    for k2 in scores[k].keys():
        scores[k][k2] = np.array(scores[k][k2])

print(scores)
```

While this method works, It feels really rudimentary, as it requires a bunch of for loops and accessing and rewriting each dict entry.

**Is there a more pythonic way of applying a function to the innermost part of a dict of dicts while keeping everything else the same?**

Comment: I think you already answered your question ;) Yes, the loops are the most pythonic. Note that you can directly loop using `for k in scores:`. You can also simplify the first loop by not tracking the keys. I'll give an example below.

Comment: You've used list comprehensions so you lost the key-value structure, there are dictionary comprehensions as well which you can replace those with. Although in your case the dict comprehension would make it quite unreadable and from the zen of Python "Readability counts" so yeah what you have might already be most pythonic.

Comment: I didn't know about dict comprehensions, but I'll add them to my arsenal right away!!

Comment: On the other hand, @mozway 's answer works fine, it just felt weird that loops are the most pythonic way, usually there are obscure functions that work better...

Comment: Explicit is better than obscure ;)

Comment: @mozway It's why pandas exists. ;-)

Comment: @blhsing it depends, if your goal is to have a dictionary, using pandas will certainly be much more expensive. You'll have to loop (internally) to convert to DataFrame, then to convert to array (`map`), then to convert back to dictionary. 3 looping steps instead of 1. Also this won't easily generalize to higher nesting levels ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops are the most pythonic, you can't really expect other approaches to have a better performance, you'll have to loop anyway.

You could simplify your code however:

```
for d in scores.values():    # let's take advantage of dictionary mutability
    for k, l in d.items():   # for each key/value
        d[k] = np.array(l)   # replace by array
```

Updated input:

```
{'default': {'MSE': array([[1., 2.],
                           [2., 3.]]),
             'R2': array([[2., 3.],
                          [3., 4.]])},
             'RBF': {'MSE': array([[3., 4.],
                                   [4., 5.]]),
             'R2': array([[4., 5.],
                          [5., 6.]])}}
```

A fix of your second approach would be to use a dictionary comprehension, but this creates a new dictionary:

```
scores = {k1: {k2: np.array(scores[k1][k2]) for k2 in scores[k1]}
          for k1 in scores}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) to efficiently apply `np.array` to all elements, and then convert the `DataFrame` back to a dict with the `to_dict` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(pd.DataFrame(scores).map(np.array).to_dict())
```

This outputs:

```
{'default': {'MSE': array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]]), 'R2': array([[2., 3.],
       [4., 5.]])}, 'RBF': {'MSE': array([[3., 4.],
       [5., 6.]]), 'R2': array([[4., 5.],
       [6., 7.]])}}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/PapayawhipSerpentineAbstracttype